# undefine empty prefix keys recursively

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

There is an emacs extension that build keys to very unhandy location and I reassign key bindings in my .emacs file just after loading extension. I've peeked into the extension code, it uses no variables or defcustoms that may be passed prior its loading.

I disable existing bindings with `(define-key ... nil)` at first, and rebind them after that.

The issue is that all prefix bindings chain remains to live and pollutes my keyboard settings.

How can I remove all empty (with no children registered) prefix key recursively?

---

update with example

Assume `map` is an empty sparse keymap.

```
(define-key map (kbd "C-c M-p b") 'do-first)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c M-p b f g") 'do-second)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c M-p b r s") 'do-third)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c M-p b r s") nil)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c M-p b f g") nil)
(define-key map (kbd "C-c M-p b") nil)
```

After that I'd like to use some kind of function like `(clean-map map)` to make `map` empty again.

Comment: Can you please give a more concrete example, to better illustrate the problem? E.g., show some of the code.

Comment: I think the issue is that if `C-c b` is not initially defined, it will remain as an "empty prefix" after the following: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b a") 'func) (global-unset-key (kbd "C-c b a"))`. ayvango would like to remove all such empty prefixes in a recursive manner (so that prefixes with only other prefixes as descendants will also be removed).

Comment: Which extension is causing the problem? If it's available in ELPA or one of the other common repos, or if I can grab the source somewhere, I'll load it up in an `emacs -q` session and play with it to see if I can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple solution.

```
(defun eab/delete-sublist (sublst lst)
  (read (replace-regexp-in-string
     (prin1-to-string sublst)
     ""
     (prin1-to-string lst))))

(defun clean-map (target-map)
  (let ((map target-map))
    (cl-flet ((clean-keymaps
        (event def)
        (if (keymapp def)
        (if (keymap-emptyp def)
            (progn
              (setq map
                (eab/delete-sublist (cons event def) map))
              (map-keymap 'clean-keymaps map))
          (map-keymap 'clean-keymaps def)))))
      (map-keymap 'clean-keymaps map)
      map)))

(defun keymap-emptyp (keymap)
  (if (keymapp keymap)
      (if (or (and
           (eq 2 (length keymap))
           (not (cdr (cadr keymap))))
          (equal keymap '(keymap)))
      't
    nil)
    nil))

(keymap-emptyp '(keymap (110))) => t
(keymap-emptyp '(keymap)) => t
(keymap-emptyp '(keymap (110) (103 . do-second))) => nil

(setq test-map (make-sparse-keymap))

(define-key test-map (kbd "C-c M-p b f k") 'do-first)
(define-key test-map (kbd "C-c M-p b f g") 'do-second)
(define-key test-map (kbd "C-c M-p b r s n") 'do-third)
(define-key test-map (kbd "C-c M-p b r s n") nil)
```

Before: there are two recursive prefix bindings, "r" and "r s".

C-c M-p b f  Prefix Command

C-c M-p b r  Prefix Command

C-c M-p b r s   Prefix Command

C-c M-p b f g   do-second

C-c M-p b f k   do-first

```
(setq test-map (clean-map test-map))
```

After: it's cleaned.

C-c M-p b f Prefix Command

C-c M-p b f g   do-second

C-c M-p b f k   do-first

Answer (score 0):

If @phils got you right, and using his example, you can do this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") nil)
```

That way the empty prefix is cleared.